# what does "bygones, sporto, bygones" mean?

Tags: meaning

Sanctuary TV series, Episode "Out of the blue":

> Will: Ok, but why bring us here? I mean, why not just bring us to the Sanctuary?
>
> Foss: Clock was ticking from the second you guys got hit. If the venom was acftive in your system too long, there was less chance that we could save you
>
> Virgil: He made a call. I opened my doors to friends.
>
> Will [*sarcastically*]: Yeah, that was really sweet of you, Virgil.
>
> Virgil: **Bygones, Sporto, bygones.** I got a big heart.

I am not getting it. Why does he call him "Sporto"? And why does he say "bygones"? Does he mean "let bygones be bygones"?

Comment: The [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sporto) sheds some light on this.

Comment: Just typing ["bygones" into a google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=bygones&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=eBptWcTcDuuw8wfhp6ugBw) will render several definitions and usages in expressions.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sporto), 'sporto' is a name for a '**jock type guy**'. In the phrase, '*bygones, sporto, bygones*', Virgil references the expression '*let bygones be bygones*', shortening it to just '*bygones*'.

So he says '*bygones, sporto*' to mean:

> let bygones be bygones, sporto<sup>1</sup>

<sub><sup>1</sup> or 'bro', 'mate' etc.</sub>

The second '*bygones*' is [repetition for effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetition_(rhetorical_device)), commonly used in speech.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that neither meaning of the word "sporto" as I understand it fits the profile of the character (Will)  as I understand it.

Comment: @Nimitta maybe it was sarcastic